# How do I suppress or remove a newline at the end of Bash command substitution?

Tags: string, bash, output

How do I suppress or remove a newline at the end of Bash [command substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html#sect_03_04_04)?

For example, I have

```
echo "$(python --version) and more text"
```

how do I get

```
Python 2.7.10 and more text
```

and not

```
Python 2.7.10
 and more text
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

bash [command substitution syntax already removes trailing newlines](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution). All you need to do is to redirect to stdout:

```
$ echo "$(python --version) and more text"
Python 2.7.8
 and more text
$ echo "$(python --version 2>&1) and more text"
Python 2.7.8 and more text
```

Comment: Ah, I see. I wasn't capturing it at all. There's no value returned, but output is generated (to stdout?), right?

Comment: And: `brew install python`.

Comment: Not on a mac. And yes, not capturing: the `$()` only captures stdout, not stderr, unless you explicitly redirect

Comment: So `python --version` goes to stderr rather than stdout? Any idea why? E.g. `echo "$(python --version 2>&1) in $(which python)"` works because `which python` goes to stdout, right?

Comment: "Why" is addressed here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26028416/7552. To test the results of a program: `which python 2>/dev/null` or `which python >/dev/null` and see if one of them has no output.

Answer (score 3):

The thing here is that `python --version` output to stderr, whereas `"and more text"` to stdout.

So the only thing you have to do is redirect stderr to stdin using `2 >&1`:

```
printf "%s and more text" "$(python --version 2>&1)"
```

or

```
$ echo "$(python --version 2>&1) and more text"
Python 2.7.10 and more text
```

---

Note that initially I was piping to `tr -d '\n'` [using `|&`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33192747/1983854):

```
echo "$(python --version |& tr -d '\n') and more text"
```

Comment: I get `-bash: command substitution: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `&'` and `-bash: command substitution: line 1: `python --version |& tr -d '\n''`.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius what version of bash are you using? See the linked question when it mentions it needs Bash 4+. A workaround is to say `python --version 2>&1 | tr -d '\n'` instead.

Comment: @fedorqui: 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin15).

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius then, as I said, use `2>&1 |` instead of `|&`.

Comment: Trimming the newlines is unnecessary when the standard error is correctly copied to standard output first. `echo "$(python --version 2>&1) and more text"`.

Comment: @chepner yes, I noticed later that the `python --version` string was stderr and not stdout. I started just saying `echo "$(python --version | tr -d '\n') and more text"`, then I just left the `tr`. Updating but trying not to just have the same answer as glenn's.