# Append output of grep filter to a file

Tags: shell, grep, tcpdump

I am trying to save the output of a grep filter to a file.

I want to run `tcpdump` for a long time, and filter a certain IP to a file.

```
tcpdump -i eth0 -n -s 0 port 5060 -vvv | grep "A.B.C."
```

This works fine. It shows me IP's from my network.

But when I add `>> file.dump` at the end, the file is always empty.

My script:

```
tcpdump -i eth0 -n -s 0 port 5060 -vvv | grep "A.B.C." >> file.dump
```

And yes, it **must** be `grep`. I don't want to use tcpdump filters because it gives me millions of lines and with grep I get only one line per IP.

How can I redirect (append) the full output of the grep command to a file?

Comment: Did you try this one : `tcpdump -i eth0 -n -s 0 port 5060 -vvv | grep 'A.B.C.' > file.dump` ?

Comment: Yes I tried, doesn't work and I want to use append, not overwrite

Comment: This is because `tcpdump` provides a continuous stream, probably through stderr. Does it work if you say `tcpdump ... |& grep --line-buffered "A.B.C."`?

Comment: If you try without grep (only for test purposes) does it correctly write into the file ? @fedorqui yes it works for me at least, I'm able to append a file from the tcpdump command (I mean, without the --line-buffered switch).

Comment: Yes! It's working with "& grep --line-buffered". Thanks fedorqui

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The output of `tcpdump` is probably going through stderr, not stdout. This means that `grep` won't catch it unless you convert it into `stdout`.

To do this you can use [`|&`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33192747/1983854):

```
tcpdump -i eth0 -n -s 0 port 5060 -vvv |& grep "A.B.C."
```

Then, it may happen that the output is a continuous stream, so that you somehow have to tell `grep` to use line buffering. For this you have the option `--line-buffered` option.

All together, say:

```
tcpdump ... |& grep --line-buffered "A.B.C" >> file.dump
```